# How to list git tags with certain format or filter

Tags: git

We would like to encode our build version number in git tags. For example, we will have git tags like this:

```
release/3.4.4/7889 
release/3.4.5/7890
release/3.4.5/7891
...
```

We know that simply calling `git tag` will give a list of git tags in the history. Is there a way to tell git to only return some tags following certain formate? For example, is that a way to find all git tags starting with `release/3.4.4/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For example, is that a way to find all git tags starting with release/3.4.4/?

If you read through the [`git tag` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag), you find:

```
git tag [-n[<num>]] -l [--contains <commit>] [--no-contains <commit>]
  [--points-at <object>] [--column[=<options>] | --no-column]
  [--create-reflog] [--sort=<key>] [--format=<format>]
  [--[no-]merged [<commit>]] [<pattern>...]
```

So, you can simply run:

```
git tag -l release/3.4.4/*
```

You may want to escape that `*` to avoid erroneous wildcard expansion
in the shell:

```
git tag -l release/3.4.4/\*
```